# Angular2 Download file [Object String] at browser (HAPI)

Tags: file, csv, angular, download, hapi.js

I'm trying to generate a csv file at server side and then send it to the client side and download the file.

In my server side I have the folowing code:
function exportUsersToCSV(request, reply) {

```
let payload = request.payload;
let users = payload.users; //array of json objects users

var fields = ["firstName", "level"];
var csv = json2csv({ data: users, fields: fields });

fs.writeFile('./../../temp/file.csv', csv, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return reply({ ok: false, message: err.message });
    }
    fs.open('file.csv', 'r', function (err, file) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("ERROR: " + err.message);
            return reply({ ok: false, message: err.message });
        }


        return reply({ ok: true, result: file, type: 'text/csv' });
    });
});
}
```

I dont now why but if I do a log of the I get a number but I see the file contente if I do:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(100);
    fs.read(file, buffer, 0, 100, 0, function (err, num) {
    console.log(buffer.toString('utf8', 0, num));
});
```

At the API I have the following:

```
return Request(options).then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                //TODO: If file...
                    if (response.type == "text/csv") {
                        console.log("API RESULT: " + response.result);
                        reply(response.result)
                            .header('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
                            .header('Content-Disposition',      'attachment; filename=file.csv');
                    } else {
                        return reply(response.result)
                    }
                } else {
                    return reply(Boom.badRequest(response.message));
                }
            })
```

At my client side I have:

```
exportUsersToCSV(users) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(
        {
            users: users
        });

    let options = Shared.getOptions();
    return this.http.post(Globals.ApiUrl +      "/admin/users/exportUsersToCSV", body, options)
        .map((res) => {
            return res.text();
        });
}
```

And then:

```
exportUsersToCSV(users) {

    this.usersService.exportUsersToCSV(users).subscribe((csvFile) => {
        let fileType = Object.prototype.toString.call(csvFile);
        console.log("fileType: " + fileType);
    },
        error => { console.error("ERROR: " + error.message) }
    );
}
```

If I do a log of the fileType I get [Object String]. Can I download this file as a CSV to my browser? If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean with "download". If you just create a link that points to a server URL that returns this file, then you don't have anything else to do in  Angular or client side JS.

Comment: Basically I have one module called Admin that send an array of users (json objects) and the server receives it and generate the file.csv. Then the server should send the file to the Admin and automatically download the file in the browser just as any normal download.

Comment: You can generated a data-url and pass it to an `<a href="...">` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs.